Tawk Messenger with Vue 3 : Set attributes in composition API
I am trying to setup the tawk widget with a Vue 3 project. The component and widget are correctly setup using this code on main.ts :
app.use(TawkMessengerVue, {
    propertyId: 'correctWidget',
    widgetId: 'default',
    setAttributes: {
        id: '1',
        phone: '123333',
        company: 'test',
        subscription: 'free'
    },
    visitor : {
        name : 'Test Tawk',
        email : 'test@test.io',
        hash: '45e592bf5a00437abfeeba2019e762a7d881b12b1d9e81a115955ed1cf4f3e74'
    }
} );

The issue is that the visitor and setAttributes and Visitor (specially visitor is the most important here) are not being passed to the widget, does anyone have any clue ? We are working with Vue 3 Composition API.
Thanks
